# Facebook custom message sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

I need to add a custom message when I hit on facebook share button on my website. By default the text says ("Say something about this..."). I would like to change this message to a custom message when when I hit the facebook share button. Is there a way I can do this with the sharer.php ? Like a parameter &t=customText ?

Comment: me too waiting for ans of this one... :(

Answer (score 0):

Right now, Facebook is not supporting the Sharer Functionality.

Something that you can do:

1. The title [title] that the Sharer is going to use is the actual  of the url that is in the parameter [url]
2. The custom message [summary] is the meta description of that [url]

***References:***

> Here is the answer from one guy of the Facebook Platform Team:
>
> Ibrahim Faour ·  · Facebook Platform Team Apologies for the
>   inconvenience. We aim to update our external reports as soon as we get
>   a resolution on issues. I do understand that sometimes the answer
>   provided may not be satisfying, but we are eager to keep our platform
>   as stable and efficient as possible. Thanks! April 24 at 5:29am
>
> For more information you can check this url:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/357750474364812/